# TP Link Powerline disconnects at very specific times

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

I have a TL-WPA4220 kit which consists of a main adapter which connects to the router and power socket next to the router, and  an extender which is plugged in upstairs. I have a Samsung Smart TV and a PS4 connected to the extender with Ethernet.

If I connect my Macbook to the upstairs SSID general browsing works fine. However, if I do a speed test (for instance at speedtest.net) the PowerLine lights will flash and it will lose connection. The second I turn on my PS4, the connection is also lost. It will then reconnect and disconnect every 5 or so seconds. If I disconnect the cable, it stops dropping, but if I try to connect the PS4 by WiFi, the same issue persists.

I am at a complete loss as to what this could be. Why do these very specific actions cause the extender to lose connection while normal web browsing doesn't?